# How do I move a body using the hardware accelerometer?

Tags: libgdx

I want to move the ball as I move the device but I can not able to find how to use accelerometer in libGDX. I know that `Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX()` returns x coordinate but I don't know how to apply it to the body I have created.

Comment: I think you can just get the x and y and apply it to your body as a velocity or acceleration. To apply it as a velocity to your object you can just do Position.X = Position.X + Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX() * ElapsedTimeInSeconds

Comment: Basically I want to move a ball on the surface using acceleration so what I did is, I apply world gravity to getAccelerometerX and getAccelerometerY in render method but I found no movement in the ball during execution.

Comment: **cfg.useAccelerometer** is not available in latest version of libgdx.

Answer (score 4):

LibGDX offers these three methods in the `com.badlogic.gdx.Input` interface:

- **float getAzimuth()**: The azimuth is the angle of the device's orientation around the z-axis. The positive z-axis points towards the earths center.
- **float getPitch()**: The pitch is the angle of the device's orientation around the x-axis. The positive x-axis roughly points to the west and is orthogonal to the z- and y-axis.
- **float getRoll()**: The roll is the angle of the device's orientation around the y-axis. The positive y-axis points to the magnetic north pole of the earth.

All three return a value in degrees. They tell you what angle the phone's being held at in the world, so you should also be able to construct a plane in your game which the ball would be sitting on, and thus determine how the ball should roll. Do note these only map perfectly to the screen if the phone is facing north, so you'd need to use the Azimuth value to find the direction of the game's local 'north' (which points towards the top or the side of the phone).

From there you just implement the physics of a ball rolling down a hill, which would mean applying acceleration to the ball depending on the direction and steepness of the ramp it's on.

Comment: sir I got all the value zero on the device when I was debugging so no value found from the device so what special thing I need to do.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing (or not doing), and in particular I've never worked with LibGDX before. At a guess, I'd say you're not actually reading from the device's accelerometer and there's something you need to do to begin accessing that information.

Answer (score 3):

I have found an answer of my question after hardworking towards it. The solution is

cfg.useAccelerometer = true;

For using accelerometer we have to enable it in the android file that this I was missing

Comment: Is that an answer to this question, or your question on my answer about getting values of zero? If it's a response to your question about getting values of zero, please don't post it as an answer to this question.